# Python Object awareness of being in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, oop, object

Is there a way in Python for an object to **'know'** what its array element id is? I.e 6  in an array, and the object itself prints out its own array element number, so '0,1,2,3,4,5'

Comment: Think of it this way: What if the object is more than one element of the sequence?

Comment: I don't know what problem you're trying to solve, but try [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: No because any object capable of doing this wouldn't be able to fit in [an array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html).  Or did you mean [list](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). The answer is still no in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The object could be inside everything and multiple objects at the same time, so it can't know unless you tell it.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no...

Answer (score 0):

Just to be pedantic: in general, no...
but technically it is *possible* for some (specific) objects, which are part of some arrays to "know their position"...

```
class HelpfulClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.arr = []

  def add(self, obj):
    pos = len(self.arr) + 1
    self.arr.append(obj)
    obj.pos = pos

class SmartObj(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.pos = None

  def print_my_element(self):
    print self.pos

if __name__ == '__main__':
  s = HelpfulClass()
  o = SmartObj()
  s.add(o)

  o.print_my_element()
```

...technically 'o' is an object...and part of an array (s.arr)...and "knows" it's position...

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you tell it, and telling it leads to very annoying coupling and/or separation of responsibility problems. What are you **really** trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use the 'enumerate' builtin to iterate over the index and the element at the same time:

```
>>> x = ['a','b','c']
>>> for index,element in enumerate(x):
...     print index,element
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Answer (score -1):

If the object knows the list it is part of, it could find out by doing `the_list.index(self)`.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: Only if no prior objects in the list compare equal to the object in question.